# phpword table column reverse

Tags: php, phpword

I am creating table using phpword and add to template. In output file, The table column are reverse in order. I have create cell correctly.

```
<?php
 $data=[
        ['cell 1 row 1','cell 2 row 1'],
        ['cell 1 row 2','cell 2 row 2']
       ];
//phpword
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\SimpleType\TblWidth;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Table;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Writer\Word2007\Element\Container;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\XMLWriter;

$fontStyle = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font();
$fontStyle->setName('Times');
$phpWord = new PhpWord();//phpword object
$section = $phpWord->addSection();//section
$tbl = $section->addTable(array(
/*'ltr' => true,*/
/*"layout" => Table::LAYOUT_AUTO,
"width"  => 100 * 50, //in word 1% == 50 unit (with in 1/50)
"unit"   => TblWidth::PERCENT,
'lineHeight' => 1*/
));
for($i=0;$i < 40;$i++){
 $tbl->addRow();
 $tbl->addCell(150)->addText("cell 1 row:$i");
 $tbl->addCell(150)->addText("cell 2 row:$i");
 $tbl->addCell(150)->addText("cell 3 row:$i");
 $tbl->addCell(150)->addText("cell 4 row:$i");
 //$tbl->addCell(150)->addMultiLineText("cell\n4 row:$i");
}

$xmlWriter = new XMLWriter(XMLWriter::STORAGE_MEMORY, './', Settings::hasCompatibility());
$containerWriter = new Container($xmlWriter, $section);
$containerWriter->write();
$elXml = $xmlWriter->getData();

// remplace our templateContent
Settings::setOutputEscapingEnabled(false);
$templateProcessor  =new TemplateProcessor('testing_tabledirection.docx');
$templateProcessor->setValue('table', $elXml);
Settings::setOutputEscapingEnabled(true);
$pathToSave     ='output_tabledirection.docx';
$templateProcessor->saveAs($pathToSave);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table column order has been fixed by removing empty array as parameter from addTable().

```
$tbl = $section->addTable(array());
```

to

```
$tbl = $section->addTable();
```

style name should passed to addTable

```
$table = $section->addTable([$tableStyle]);
```

Step to define table style

1. create array and define style for table

> **$tableStyle** = array(
> 'borderColor' => '006699',
> 'borderSize'  => 6,
> 'cellMargin'  => 50
> );

2. define style to phpword object

> $phpWord->addTableStyle('**myTable**', **$tableStyle**);

3. Add style when create table from section

> $table = $section->addTable('**myTable**');